# jquery and php utf-8 encode decode

Tags: php, jquery

hi in my project i am making a turkish letter checkking script.
if a user enters a key is not a turkish letter give a warning .

this is my jquery code

```
$( "#singup_surname" ).keyup(function() {
var singup_surname = $( "#singup_surname" ).val().trim();

var request = $.ajax({
      url: "check.php",
      type: "POST",
      encoding:"UTF-8",
      data: { singup_surname_only:singup_surname},
      dataType: "html"
    });
request.done(function( msg ) {
    msg=msg.trim();

  if(msg=="ok"){
      $('#singup_surname').removeClass('wrongField');
      $('#singup_surname').addClass('trueField');
  }else if(msg=="no"){
      $('#singup_surname').removeClass('trueField')
      $('#singup_surname').addClass('wrongField')

  }else {
      alert("database connection error");
  }

});

});
```

for example if user enters "ş" letter post send like this

```
singup_surname_only=%C5%9F
```

on the php side this is my code

```
$singup_surname_only=$_POST['singup_surname_only'];
if (isset($singup_surname_only)) {
$singup_surname_only=urldecode($singup_surname_only);

$tk = array('A','B','C','Ç','D','E','F','G','Ğ','H','I','İ','J','K','L','M','N','O','Ö','P','R','S','Ş','T','U','Ü','V','Y','Z','a', 'b', 'c','ç', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g','ğ', 'h', 'i','ı', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 
             'n', 'o','ö', 'p', 'r', 's','ş','t','u','ü', 'v','y','z' ) ;
$tk=array("%C5%9F","ö");
$arr1 = str_split($singup_surname_only);
$letterCount = count($arr1);
$i=1;
while ($i<=$letterCount) {
    if (in_array($arr1["$i"], $tk)) {

        }else echo 'no';
        $i++;
}




}
```

what i see is on php side in my array 'ş' letter becomes something like this 'Å'

how to solve this problem thank you very much

Comment: "becomes something like this 'Å'" --- how do you know it becomes `Å`?

Comment: i added these codes to php side to see what is going on        print_r($tk);
 echo"<br>";
 print_r($arr1);
 echo"<br>";
 print_r($letterCount);
 echo"<br>";
 print_r($i);
 echo"<br>";

Comment: And the page encoding when you're doing it is... ?

Comment: i saw it on firebug net post response .

Comment: and what encoding does firebug use for the response display? Are you sure it's `Å` not `ÅŸ`?

Comment: It doesn't answer the question about encoding. For the characters to be displayed correctly it must be `utf-8`. Is it `utf-8` in firebug?

Comment: Btw, `str_split` is not multi-byte friendly function. You cannot use it for `utf-8` strings. So seems like you've broken the data with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how you could check if there are only Turkish characters in a string `$str`:

```
$tkReg = sprintf('~^[%s]*$~u', join('', $tk));
$thereAreOnlyTurkishCharacters = preg_match($tkReg, $str) === 1;

var_dump($thereAreOnlyTurkishCharacters);
```